# Generating an ordered list of directories

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a project that consists of several modules (which then contains modules in their place). After the entire build is done I use the maven-assembly-plugin to put together a distribution of the build including some scripts that I want to run when deploying the files. The modules are mostly ear files containing one or more war.

The assembly contains a structure of directories named with the same name as the ear project and it contains the deployable ear file. So far all is good, but when I later want to use the built files with the scripts I have the order (decided by the order they are the built, which is the order the modules are listed in the main pom, is important. I have tried this using the timestamp of the directory in which they reside, but unfortunately that information gets lost when we copy the fails over to another machine. Even with a zipped version containing the same version, the timestamps get lost with our company-wide provide unzipping tools.

My idea is now to generate a list of the directories where the ear files are and put them either in a text file or a property (comma-separated), which then can be read by the scripts to provide the correct order.

My pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    .
    .
    .
    <modules>
        <module>SubProject1-Project/SubProject1-module</module>
        <module>SubProject2-Project/SubProject2-module</module>
        <module>SubProject3-Project/SubProject3-module</module>
        <module>SubProject4-Project/SubProject4-module</module>     
        <module>SubProject5-Project/SubProject5-module</module>
    </modules>
    <!-- Once all the modules are complete, the built packages are gathered up. -->
    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-${maven.build.timestamp}</finalName>
        <plugins> 
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>src/main/assembly/MyAssemblyDescriptor.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>                      
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>                     
                        </manifest>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Implementation-Version>${project.version}-${maven.build.timestamp}</Implementation-Version>
                            <Implementation-Build>${project.version}-${maven.build.timestamp}</Implementation-Build>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>                  
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>       
        </plugins>  
    </build>
</project>
```

MyAssemblyDescriptor.xml:

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.0.xsd">

    <id>distribution</id>
    <formats>
        <format>dir</format>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <moduleSets>
        <moduleSet>
            <sources>
                <fileSets>
                    <fileSet>
                        <outputDirectory>.</outputDirectory>
                        <directory>target</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*.ear</include>
                            <include>**/*-distribution.zip</include>
                        </includes> 
                    </fileSet>      
                </fileSets>
            </sources>
        </moduleSet>
    </moduleSets>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>  
</assembly>
```

This produces a directory file structure of:

```
SubProject1EAR\SubProject1EAR.ear
SubProject2EAR\SubProject2EAR.ear
SubProject3EAR\SubProject3EAR.ear
SubProject4EAR\SubProject4EAR.ear
SubProject5EAR\SubProject5EAR.ear
```

where the SubProject1EAR is a sub-module of SubProject1-module above and son on.

Based on all of this I want to generate a list of the EAR project names (also the name of the directory where each EAR ends up) in the correct order. Is there any maven plugin or other maven setup that will help me produce that? I have tried looking at the maven-assembly-plugin and the maven reactor plugin but could not find anything that would help me.